# Syntax error in Python 2

Tags: python

I have a homework to do and i did it. I am 95 % sure its a corect code. I dont have a clue why but unfortunally i got  Syntax error in one of the lines. Here is my code:

```
month = 1
totalPaid = 0
while month <= 12:
    print('Month: ' + str(month))
    print('Minimum monthly payment: ' + str(round(monthlyPaymentRate * balance), 2)
    balance = round((balance - (monthlyPaymentRate * balance)) * (1 + (annualInterestRate/12)),2)
    print('Remaining balance: ' + str(round(balance, 2)))
    month = month + 1
    totalPaid = totalPaid + round((monthlyPaymentRate * balance), 2)
print('Total paid: ' + str(totalPaid))
print('Remaining balance: ' + str(balance))
```

I got Syntax error on this line: balance = round((balance - (monthlyPaymentRate * balance)) * (1 + (annualInterestRate/12)),2). It is probably something very simple but i am novice in Python and cant understand what exactly is the problem, i know that Python is very sensative about spaces and indents and i was carefull about that. Any suggestions ?

Comment: The `homework` tag is being phased out; please do not add it to posts anymore.

Comment: -1 for being 95% sure the Python interpreter knows less about Python syntax than you do. Get an editor that can match parens.

Comment: Thank you, sir ! May i have another, sir ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
print('Minimum monthly payment: ' + str(round(monthlyPaymentRate * balance), 2)
```

has three open parens, but two close parens.